# cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char [25]' to 'SAFEARRAY *'

Tags: c#, c++, com-interop, safearray

I have a `char sendBuf[sizeof(double)*3 + 1];` in my c++ code.

My c# com code method `Multicast( byte[] message)` takes byte array as argument.

so why doesnt the call Multicast(sendBuf) throw this error `cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char [25]' to 'SAFEARRAY *'`

isnt a char array a byte array in c/c++

also how do I convert this char* to safearray then?

I tried

```
SAFEARRAYBOUND bound[1] = {25, 0};
SAFEARRAY * psa = SafeArrayCreate(VT_UI1, 1, bound);

for(int i = 0; i <25; i++){
SafeArrayPutElement(psa, &i, sendBuf[i]);
```

but get `cannot convert parameter 2 from 'int *' to 'LONG *'` for `SafeArrayPutElement`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Documentation for the SAFEARRAY APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221145.aspx)

Start with [`SafeArrayCreateVector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b794b8c6-a523-4636-8681-a936dff3fc6f%28VS.85%29)